# Copado vs Flosum

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, automation, release, pipelines

Are there any good comparison between Copado Vs Flosum ? I understand that there are individual choices around these tools but I am looking for a platform which maximizes the developer productivity. Any indicators on price would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't generally offer product comparisons on this network. For one, tools are not one-size-fits-all. If I had a preference for one over the other, that would be because one suited *my goals* better than the other. *My goals* may not be *your goals*, and *my* checklist of features are not necessarily *your* checklist of features.

In other words, any product review or comparison would be subjective, which is against our network's guidelines. That said, you might do a search engine query for "flosum vs copado" and see what you find. You should also do your own research, get some trials or guided tours from Sales, etc. Review sites, such as [this one](https://www.g2.com/compare/copado-vs-flosum), may offer you more insight. Note that I am not endorsing this site, simply pointing out an example.

You may also simply find another, third system that's even better than one of the two you've suggested here. The more research you do, the more likely it is you'll find the tools you need to maximize your CI/CD experience.